# '!' illegal operation on bound member function expression

Tags: c++

I am doing a simple code on identifying even and odd numbers in a text file using

Here is my code, the only error I supposedly get is the exclamation mark in the while loop

```
     #include <iostream>
     #include <fstream>
     using namespace std;

     int main()
    {
     int even = 0, odd = 0;
     int value;
     ifstream file3("evenodd.txt");

while (!file3.eof) {
    file3 >> value;
    if (value % 2 == 0) {
        even++;
    }
    else {
        odd++;
    }
    cout << " Even count: " << even << " ";
    cout << "Odd count: " << odd << " ";
 }
 }
```

Comment: `file3.eof` is the address of a member function.  As such, the expression `!file3.eof` is invalid, and wouldn't actually check if the end of `file3` has been reached since it doesn't call the member function.   You probably intend the loop to do `while (!file3.eof())`.   Doing that is a bad idea though -  read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons for more information

Comment: Thank you for the answer, noted.

Answer (score 1):

`eof` is a  function so the code need to look like this `while (!file3.eof())`.